# Unable to decode response from ejabberd server in a Node.js application

Tags: node.js, ejabberd

I am a completely newbie to node.js. Please i need your help with the code below. I have tried executing it but i am not able to decode the response from the server. Thanks for your time and efforts.

```
var express = require('express');

var xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// Creates an XML-RPC server to listen to XML-RPC method calls
var server = xmlrpc.createServer({ host: 'localhost', port: 9090 });
// Handle methods not found
server.on('NotFound', function(method, params) {
  console.log('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
});
// Handle method calls by listening for events with the method call name
server.on('anAction', function (err, params, callback) {
  console.log('Method call params for \'anAction\': ' + params);

  // ...perform an action...

  // Send a method response with a value
  callback(null, 'aResult');
});
console.log('XML-RPC server listening on port 9091');



// Waits briefly to give the XML-RPC server time to start up and start
// listening

var receiveraray;
setTimeout(function () {
  // Creates an XML-RPC client. Passes the host information on where to
  // make the XML-RPC calls.

  var client = xmlrpc.createClient({ host: 'host', port: 4560,  path: '/home/ec2-user/ejabberd-15.07/bin'});

  // Sends a method call to the XML-RPC server{call, user_resources, 

  client.methodCall('registered_users', [ {host: "host"} ], function (error, value) {
  //client.methodCall('ejabberdctl status', function (error, value) {
    // Results of the method response

    receiveraray = value;
    console.log('Method response for \'anAction\': ' + receiveraray);
    console.log('Method response for \'anAction\': ' + error);
  });

}, 1000);
```

I am getting this output from this response from the ejabberd server;

Method response for 'anAction': [object Object]
Method response for 'anAction': null

Comment: Did you try `console.log('Method response for \'anAction\': %j', receiveraray);` or `console.dir(receiveraray)` instead, in order to see the object properties?

Comment: Hi mscdex, thanks for responding. This is what i got. 2015-08-08T15:57:48.63+0100 [App/0]   OUT { users: [] }

Comment: users: [] } . From the ejabberd server i ran the same command and got the list of users. I am not sure if the response is in xml and needs to be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you parameter for access ejabberd XMLRPC listener are incorrect:

```
var client = xmlrpc.createClient({ host: 'host', port: 4560,  path: '/home/ec2-user/ejabberd-15.07/bin'});
```

You are pointing to `host`, I guess you mean `localhost`.
The path seems completely broken. You are trying to access a directory. Typically, you probably want path to be "/" as you mean to access `http://localhost:4560/` to pass XMLRPC requests (depends on your actual ejabberd configuration).

Comment: Hi Mickael, thanks for the response. I used 'host' because i am using a private server of which i am required to keep it's details private. The node.js and ejabberd server reside in separate domains. At moment, the command executes successfully, i am just getting the response as {object, Object}